# Query to get Execution Plan() as output in Denodo

Tags: denodo

Select * from view_name trace is giving me the query output which is the view data but I’m unable to get the execution trace as data.
Please hlp me to get the execution trace or EXECUTION PLAN() as output so that I can redirect the same to a file for further analysis or manipulation. Is there any API available for the same?
Please let me know if my further information is required.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the query from the administration tool of Denodo, the trace shows up on a tab of the VQL Shell.

Currently, there is no API to obtain the trace of a query.